# Type error in cv2.getRotationMatrix2D - Only Size-1 Arrays can be converted to Python Scalars

Tags: opencv, python

I am trying to use the cv2 get rotation matrix 2D to perform a simple rotation but getting the type error. I assume it may because of cv2 or numpy version and hence giving the details below.
cv2 version - 4.2.0
numpy version - 1.18.4
Python - 3.7.3

```
image= cv2.imread('4.jpg')
(h,w) = image[:2]
center=(w//2,h//2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,45,1)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image,M,(w,h))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(rotated,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-930e769f51b7> in <module>
      2 (h,w) = image[:2]
      3 center=(w//2,h//2)
----> 4 M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,45,1)
      5 rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image,M,(w,h))
      6 plt.axis('off')

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line,

```
(h,w) = image[:2]
```

to,

```
(h,w) = image.shape[:2]
```

`image[:2]` returns an array not the dimensions of the image